# users with bin/bash access

Tags: bash, permissions, login, postgresql, passwd

I was following the guide [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-users-command/) and listed all users in passwd. There I found the following problems:

`/bin/false` aparently allows channels and some form of [forwarding](http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/ssh-security/)

```
nm-openconnect:x:122:130:NetworkManager OpenConnect plugin,,,:/var/lib/NetworkManager:/bin/false
```

is this forwarding still possible with `/bin/false` nowadays (16.02)?

```
guest-2lq2jn:x:998:997:Guest:/tmp/guest-2lq2jn:/bin/bash
```

I don't know who this is or why this account exists. Its history is empty but it does seem to have root access. What should I do?

```
postgres:x:123:132:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

Why does postgreSQL have `/bin/bash` access? Is this normal?

I am sorry for asking three questions in one, but it can be hard to get one answered and it seems like they are sub-questions.

Comment: I guess the psql issue is [known](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158014/why-does-postgres-require-a-shell). The guest should be removed, but any way to check it didn't backdoor my computer? The forwarding, is it unsafe?

Comment: What makes you say that `guest-2lq2jn` has root access?

Comment: It seems to have a chroot or jail. These accounts came with KVM I think, my login screen has a QEMU login name, I'm not 100% sure when it appeared because my computer is always on.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/false` is a simple program which does nothing, and returns a status code indicating failure. you can still use it. It's a part of `coreutils` package so it's available by default.

"guest" line is related to Ubuntu guest user and does not have any harm or any spacial permissions to do anything to your system, it's a normal user which has access to bash however it can do nothing and all it's data are temporary.

about "postgres", it might need a bash to do a specific task.